# NHibernate Cascade.None still updates parent entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have some entities (for sake of simplicity it looks like that):

```
class DbEntity
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

class BaseEntity: DbEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ParentEntity Parent {get;set;}       
}

class ParentEntity: BaseEntity
{
    List<BaseEntity> Children {get;set;}
}

class ChildEntity: BaseEntity
{

}
```

Now, my fluent mappings look like that:

```
class DbEntityMap<T>: ClassMap<T> where T: DbEntity
{
    public DbEntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    }
}

class BaseEntityMap: DbEntityMap<BaseEntity>
{
    UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
    Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();

    References(x => x.Parent).Cascade.None();
}

class ParentEntityMap: SubclassMap<ParentEntity>
{
   Abstract();
   HasMany(x => x.Children)
       .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
       .Inverse()
       .Not.KeyUpdate()
       .Cascade.None()
       .LazyLoad();
}

class ChildEntityMap: SubclassMap<ChildEntity>
{
   Abstract();
   //some other stuff
}
```

Now, I have client desktop application that sends request to WebAPI.
The first request is to create all entities, like for example:

```
ParentEntity parent = new ParentEntity();
parent.Name = "New name";

ChildEntity child1 = new ChildEntity();
ChildEntity child2 = new ChildEntity();

parent.Children.Add(child1);
parent.Children.Add(child2);

//of course children know their parent:
//child.Parent = parent;
```

Now I am building some dto from that (because my model is much more complicated and creating a dto is good idea) to build a json, and send this json to WebAPI. Entities in database are created properly. Great.

But now I have to modify some child entity, for example:

```
child1.SomeValue = newValue;
```

Now, while creating DTO I don't add parent entity to that, just parent id and it looks more less like that:

```
class ChildDto
{
    public Guid DbId {get;set;}
    public Guid ParentDbId {get;set;}
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when my WebAPI receives such dto it recreates a model like that:

```
ParentEntity fakeParent = new ParentEntity();
fakeParent.Id = childDto.ParentDbId;

ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
//assign other child values and then parent:
child.Parent = fakeParent;
```

Now when I do Update(just session.Update(obj, id)) my child entity updates properly, BUT parent entity updates also. As I didn't set Name property in parent entity, Name field in database becomes empty.

I thought that setting Cascade to None would prevent NHibernate from updating parent entity. But no Cascade setting works. If I set the parent binding to:

```
References(x => x.Parent).ReadOnly()
```

then my ChildEntity is updated without parent id.

I know at least couple of solutions for that like:
1. Transform also whole parent entity in DTO - but this can make other cascade updates and if not - there will be two updates instead of one.
2. Select parent entity just before update - but this creates unnecessary SELECT.

What I would like to achieve is:
- update ONLY childEntity - without updating parent nor any other entity.

How can I acomplish that?

**[Some words about actual application]**

In reality my ParentEntity could hold BaseEntities. ParentEntity and ChildEntity have also some common properties.

What's more ChildEntity can hold other DbEntities.
Children of child entity also hold other DbEntities, it looks like that:

ParentEntity -> ChildEntity -> EntityA -> EntityB -> EntityC
(like a tree)

(every derives from DbEntity).
And I even managed to solve the problem using session.Merge, but when I try to UPDATE for example EntityA the problem is the same - ChildEntity loses connection with ParentEntity :|

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that setting Cascade to None would prevent NHibernate from updating parent entity. But no Cascade setting works

You are expecting that `Cascade.None` will prevent updating associations. Though this is true, this is not the case in your code. The parent entity is being updated because of your *strange* inheritance hierarchy. I do not understand need of multi-level inheritance. If you remove `BaseEntity`, what you are willing to achieve will happen without need to call `Load`.

The scenario you are working is explained [here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html):

> **10.4.2. Updating detached objects**
>
> Many applications need to retrieve an object in one transaction, send it to the UI layer for manipulation, then save the changes in a new transaction. ........
>   This approach requires a slightly different programming model to the one described in the last section. NHibernate supports this model by providing the method ISession.Update().

You should also have look at [this](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html):

> **10.10. Lifecycles and object graphs**
>
> The precise semantics of cascading operations are as follows:
>
> - **If a parent is saved, all children are passed to SaveOrUpdate()**
> - If a parent is passed to Update() or SaveOrUpdate(), all children are passed to SaveOrUpdate()
> - If a transient child becomes referenced by a persistent parent, it is passed to SaveOrUpdate()
> - If a parent is deleted, all children are passed to Delete()
> - If a transient child is dereferenced by a persistent parent, nothing special happens (the application should explicitly delete the child if necessary) unless cascade="all-delete-orphan" or cascade="delete-orphan", in which case the "orphaned" child is deleted.

Notice the highlighted point above. Your both `ParentEntity` and `ChildEntity` derive from `BaseEntity`. Further, `BaseEntity` holds the association property `ParentEntity Parent`. When you `Update` child entity, your parent entity is passed to `SaveOrUpdate`. As you have not specified `Name` there, it updates the database with empty name.

> If I set the parent binding to:
>
> ```
> References(x => x.Parent).ReadOnly()
> ```
>
> then my ChildEntity is updated without parent id.

This is obvious; you explicitly set it to read only.

Comment: I need such inheritance because in my real code ParentEntity has list of BaseEntity. ParentEntity and ChildEntity have some common properties. And when I try to do mapping without subclassing, I get an error saying that BaseEntity is not mapped. So I'm a little stuck.

Comment: @AdamJachocki: I said the inheritance is strange because `ParentEntity` also holds the association property for itself. You can bypass `BaseEntity` shifting its members to `ParentEntity` and derive `ChildEntity` from `ParentEntity`. But; I am not much aware about your actual application; that is why I asked you to just do this for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You should `session.Load` existing objects that you don't want to update (do not confuse it with `session.Get` - it wouldn't issue  SELECT statement for lazy entities).

So you need to change your DTO -> Entity conversion logic to something like this:

```
ParentEntity fakeParent = session.Load<ParentEntity>(childDto.ParentDbId);

ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
//assign other child values and then parent:
child.Parent = fakeParent;
```

Comment: But this not only requires unnecessary SELECTs, but also is quite drammatic in my case. Because I do something like this: foreach(var item in itemsToModify) session.Update(item). And I don't really know the type of object that I am pushing to database. I would need to check the type first and this would be really drammatic.

Comment: I have many more entities. Some of them don't have any parent or have parent from various tables. So It would be really hard and inefficient to implement something like this.

Comment: So you're suggesting that instead of update I should call Load and then update?

Comment: @AdamJachocki You have some code that transforms `childDto.ParentDbId` to `fakeParent` entity object. I say that this transformation should look like `session.Load<ParentType>(parentId)` and this results should be assigned to `childEntity.ParentProperty`. So what makes creation of fake ParentType with only Id specified acceptable to you and and calling `session.Loade<ParentType>(parentId)` instead unacceptable?

Comment: This is done in two different layers of application. And while saving the entity in database I do not know its type at all.

Comment: @AdamJachocki My last attempt on it :) I updated answer with how I think you should convert your DTO objects to entities. You mentioned multiple times that to make it work you need to do some type checking and `while saving the entity in database I do not know its type at all.`.  My answer didn't  mention any of it. So please clarify how it's related to my suggestion?

Comment: Because there is a deep tree hierarchy and I really don't know what to load without type checking. And now I think that I would have to load whole the tree all the way up just to do one update :|

Comment: `childDto.ParentDbId` in DTO is just scalar property. You somehow know that it's `Id` for `ParentType` object. And your have some logic that detects such scalar property and converts it to "fake object". So I still don't understand why this logic "scalar property -> fake entity conversion" can't be modified as I suggested. You don't need to check any tree and load entities beforehand.

Comment: It's more complicated. This conversion is done on Model Layer that knows nothing about DAL. That's why I am not able to load it in this place. I would have to do some type switch in service layer and then check - if this is a ChildEntity then load ParentEntity. If this is a EntityA, then load ChildEntity and ParentEntity. And so on.